# Python: How to create a lookup table for string matching

Tags: python, python-2.7, lookup, string-matching

I need to parse each row of a csv and add a new column by matching if an existing column matches a pattern. For example, if columnA starts with the string `elephant` then I will add a new column called `Mammal`.

So, the file is like

```
uid   datetime         description 
 1    2015-09-01       an elephant has trunks
 2    2015-08-31       there are sharks in the sea
```

So, I want to search the `description` column and add a new column called `animal` which will identify the type of animal we are talking about. So, the new csv will be

```
uid   datetime         description                       animal
 1    2015-09-01       an elephant has trunks            mammal
 2    2015-08-31       there are sharks in the sea       fish
```

This is a rather simplified example but I essentially need to create a lookup for the animal type and the description.

Comment: Do you mean different rows of the same csv should have different columns? Wouldn't that make the csv have invalid structure?

Comment: no. I just want a new column based on matching an existing column with the lookup dictionary. the same column for each row.

Comment: Can you explain your case with an example?

Comment: I have done that. Hope that makes it more clear.

Comment: What will you do with the description, "River otters eat mussels and beetles?"

Comment: @saulspatz we can just look at the first one that matches our lookup and have that. so this will be otters = mammals.

Answer (score 4):

You can make your lookup table a dict.

```
beasts["otter"] = "mammal"
beasts["porgy"] = "fish"
```

You'll probably want to add plurals also.

```
beasts["porgies"] = "fish"
beasts["foxes"] = "mammal"
```

Then you just need to split the description in to words, look up the words in your dict, and classify the description by the first word found:

```
for word in description.split():
    if word in beasts:
         classification = beasts[word]
         break
else:
   print("Unclassified")
```

Note that this is a loop `else`.  It needs to be indented at the same level as the `for`.  I don't really like loop elses, because if the loop gets long, it's easy to get the indentation wrong, and the bug can be hard to find, but if the loop is short, as in the above example, they're great. If you need to do more in the loop than I've shown, you may want to substitute a different construct.  (Also, "beasts" is obviously a rotten name for the dict.  Think of a better one, please.)